# ModX: getResources from document and documents children

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, getresource

I want to use getResources to get the content from a document, and its child documents. I believe I can used `&depth` to do this but I cannot seem to get it working.

I have tried 2 approaches:

```
echo "[[!getResources?  $parents=`15`  &includeTVs=`1` &resources=`" . $resid . "` &depth=`1` &tpl=`tendertmp`]]";
```

and:

```
echo "[[!getResources? $parents=`" . $resid . "` &depth=`1` &includeTVs=`1` &tpl=`tendertmp`]]";
```

`$resid` is just a number generated by a snippet - the first example works fine without depth.

Would anyone know the correct way of using depth or a way to get the reources content along with its child resources content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why you do not use http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/modX.runSnippet ?

```
$output = $modx->runSnippet('getResources',array(
   'parents' => $resid,
   'depth' => '1',
   'includeTVs' => '1',
   'tpl' => 'tendertmp'
));
echo $output;
```

and your second mistake in `$parents` instead `&parents`.

Answer (score 0):

I actually do not understand why you are attempting to run getResources from within a PHP Snippet.  There is very little reason to do so.

You could simple do a `$modx->getCollection('modResource, $someCriteriaHere);`  or

Call getResources directly from your pages:

```
[[!getResources?parents=`15`&includeTVs=`1`&depth=`1`&tpl=`tendertmp`]]
```